# Is it okay to do the following substitution in a real integral?

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, real-numbers

just a simple question. If i have a real integral (on the real line) , am i allowed to do a substitution such as this one?

let u = it

du = i dt

Thank you very much in advance for all your help and time.

Comment: Yes, you can. provided you change the contour of integration from real axis to imaginary axis. BTW, pay special attention when the integration limit involves $\pm \infty$. Under above substitution, the limit becomes $\mp i \infty$. A lot of students fail to recognize the integration limits points to different infinities and draw wrong conclusions about the integral.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in general there is no problem with that. If $f=u+iv$ when $u,v:A\subset\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ then $\int f=\int u+i\int v$. If you follow that rule then there is no problem to change variables with complex numbers.